# Cannot connect to Informix Dynamic Server using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, informix

I have installed Informix 14.10 on my local machine for developing an application using Spring Boot JPA and Hibernate.

But when I run the application I get the following error:

> Socket connection to server (ol_informix1410@localhost:9088) failed. Check your server is reachable from this client on the host:port specified.

Here is my application.yml with the necessary data:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:informix-sqli://localhost:9088/sigba:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_informix1410
    driver-class-name: com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
    username: ${dbusername}
    password: ${dbpassword}
  jpa:
    databasePlatform: org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect
    showSql: true
    generateDdl: true
    hibernate:
      ddlAuto: update
```

I also tried to connect from DBeaver 23 using the same information and even trying to connect with telnet to my ip:port fails. I am sure that the port is correct because it is the one I put on the installation.

Accessing with dbaccess works fine. The system is installed on Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: You can try using the IP address of your local machine instead of localhost, may or may not help.

Comment: @tgdavies I tried but it doesn't work too

Comment: You can check the port name or number used in the Informix server's sqlhosts file. From the cmd window Start menu item created during the Informix install the environment variable INFORMIXSQLHOSTS should point to this file where the 3rd column will list localhost or 127.0.0.1 and the 4th column will be the port number or name. This info should match what is shown in the registry HKLM\SOFTWARE\Informix\SQLHOSTS\ol_informix1410 (in your case).
In dbaccess also check you are connecting to the same port using the Connection menu item.

Comment: Also check that the INFORMIXSERVER value you are using matches that assigned to the host name + service entry in the sqlhosts file. In your example ol_informix1410 may be assigned to the entry for the server's real name / IP address. The name used for the localhost entry by default starts with lo_ (although you can assign any name you choose during the install).